# How to make this command open a new terminal & execute the command within it ( Exec=bash -c "tail -n 10 -f /var/log/httpd/error_log" )

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, gnome

This is simply a shortcut for the panel.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=bash -c "tail -n 10 -f /var/log/httpd/error_log"
Type=Application
Icon=/root/Desktop/2.svg
```

i need that Exec= command to open a new terminal
and run the command in it.

Comment: Which terminal application are you using? Most support a command line option to run a command after opening the window. eg, "gnome-terminal -e 'echo hi'" would open a terminal and then run that command.

Comment: ...what's with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365156/we-finally-found-some-info-on-this-troll)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a terminal `Exec=nameOfYourTerminalApp` (eg:gnome-terminal, lxterminal, xterm)
Then you can run your commands in the opened terminal. 
Otherwise, you can create a script with some command and run it.
In that case you have to put `tail -n 10 -f /var/log/httpd/error_log` in the script and make it executable. Then call it with a shortcut file.